# Storing scraped values in csv files

Tags: selenium, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I am doing LinkedIn web scraping as a part of my college project. I have scraped the experience and education section of a profile. After doing that, I want to save it in a csv file as shown in the code below. But it is getting stored as an object address and not the actual value. How do I save the actual values of experience and education, and not the object address?

```
#Code to scrape experience and education sections of a LinkedIn profile
experience = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#experience-section .pv-profile-section')
education = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.education-section ')

with open('linkedin.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Sr. No.", "Experience", "Education"])
    writer.writerow([1, experience, education])
```

It is getting saved like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
experiencetext= [x.text for x in experience]
```

Convert it into a list of text. Then pass it.

Comment: I tried using that but it is storing the values with '\n' tags. How do I remove those?

['Intern\nCompany Name\nMedTourEasy Internship\nDates Employed\nApr 2020 – Jun 2020\nEmployment Duration\n3 mos\nWorked in the data visualization field to collect & analyse data; and create user interactive dashboards on COVID-19. Created COVID-19 worldwide and testing tracker to gain meaningful insights. Leveraged PowerBI, Tableau and R.']

Comment: x.text.replace("\n","")